# Deleting rows based on a calculated criteria in R

Tags: r, for-loop, rows, lapply

I conducted an analysis for some M&A-Deals. My current output looks like this:

```
Deal-Nr | Event-Date  | Target-Nation | CAR  | SIC
----------------------------------------------------
1       |  01-01-1999 | Italy         | 5.1% | 201
2       |  02-01-1999 | Germany       | 2.3% | 202
3       |  06-01-1999 | Spain         | 1.5% | 201
4       |  10-09-1999 | Germany       | 0.3% | 201
5       |  15-09-1999 | UK            | 1.1% | 201
6       |  25-10-2000 | Spain         | 0.8% | 201
```

However, for my final analysis I want to exclude all deals within the same SIC-Code, which do not have at least 180 trading days between them. So in this case, I would want to exclude my deal 3 from the analysis (as they have the same SIC-code and do not have 180 days between them). Then the code should continue and check the next deal within that SIC-Code industry and remove (<180 days) or keep it (>180 days). This should be done for all the different SIC codes in my analysis.

As I'm rather new in R, I'm reaching out for help. Thank you so much for your support.

Edit:
As indicated below I provide some further information. I'm interested in the deals that are in the same SIC-Code and >180 days apart. This would mean in the table to remove row (3) and row (5). If one deal is more than 180 days apart the subsequent dates should be checked.

Comment: What if an SIC code is >180 days from the first date but <180 days from the second or even subsequate dates? ie 1-1-1990, 1-6-1990, 1-10-1990, 1-3-1991. NOte that the first date(1-1-1990) is maintained. then 1-6-1990 is not >180 days from 1-1-1990. so it will be removed.  But 1-10-1990  is <180 from 1-6-1990 but >180 from 1-1-1990. Should it be maintained or removed? also 1-3-1991 is >180 from the first date but <180 when considering 1-10-1990. Should it be removed or maintained?

Comment: In general, providing data in an easy-to-use format would help to engage more people to respond. in the current form they have to construct the data.frame manually which can be a deterrent.

Answer (score 0):

First, your `Event.Date` column needs to be a real date, not a string. I'm inferring month-day-year. From there, we need to group by `SIC` and calculate the difference in dates.

### base R

```r
dat$Event.Date <- as.Date(dat$Event.Date, format = "%d-%m-%Y")
keep <- ave(as.numeric(dat$Event.Date), dat$SIC, FUN = function(z) c(TRUE, diff(z) >= 180)) > 0
dat[keep,]
#   Deal.Nr Event.Date Target.Nation  CAR SIC
# 1       1 1999-01-01         Italy 5.1% 201
# 2       2 1999-01-02       Germany 2.3% 202
# 4       4 1999-09-10       Germany 0.3% 201
# 6       6 2000-10-25         Spain 0.8% 201
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
#   mutate(Event.Date = as.Date(Event.Date, format = "%d-%m-%Y")) %>%
#   group_by(SIC) %>%
#   filter(c(TRUE, diff(Event.Date) >= 180)) %>%
#   ungroup()
# . + # A tibble: 4 x 5
#   Deal.Nr Event.Date Target.Nation CAR     SIC
#     <int> <date>     <chr>         <chr> <int>
# 1       1 1999-01-01 Italy         5.1%    201
# 2       2 1999-01-02 Germany       2.3%    202
# 3       4 1999-09-10 Germany       0.3%    201
# 4       6 2000-10-25 Spain         0.8%    201
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(dat
#   )[, Event.Date := as.Date(Event.Date, format = "%d-%m-%Y")
#   ][, .SD[c(TRUE, diff(Event.Date) >= 180),], by = .(SIC)]
+ >    SIC Deal.Nr Event.Date Target.Nation  CAR
# 1: 201       1 1999-01-01         Italy 5.1%
# 2: 201       4 1999-09-10       Germany 0.3%
# 3: 201       6 2000-10-25         Spain 0.8%
# 4: 202       2 1999-01-02       Germany 2.3%
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(Deal.Nr = 1:6, Event.Date = c("01-01-1999", "02-01-1999", "06-01-1999", "10-09-1999", "15-09-1999", "25-10-2000"), Target.Nation = c("Italy", "Germany", "Spain", "Germany", "UK", "Spain"), CAR = c("5.1%", "2.3%", "1.5%", "0.3%", "1.1%", "0.8%"), SIC = c(201L, 202L, 201L, 201L, 201L, 201L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your reply. This was already quite helpful and worked partially. The main issues goes back to @Onyambu's point. The goal is to remove just the deals, which are <180 days from the previous deal. So as an example:

1. Deal. 01-01-1990
2. Deal. 30-01-1990 (remove, as <180 days from 1. Deal)
3. Deal. 30-07-1990 (keep, as >180 from 1. Deal)
4. Deal 30-08-1990 (remove as <180 days from 2. Deal).

Comment: Doesn't my answer do this? Your question said to remove row 3, and this removes row 3 because the days between it (SIC 201) and the previous SIC 201 is not over 180.

Comment: No, your answer works perfectly fine for this small sample dataset. However, the actual dataset is much bigger. Thus, I ran into some issues and I was wondering whether you actually know how to solve this issue.

Comment: I know how to solve what you have provided. If it doesn't work in other cases, then it is up to you to update your data to reflect what is different.

Comment: I updated the answer based on your additional data. The *only* change necessary was that I switched the date format from mdy to dmy/ FYI, date formats are horribly irregular, and despite being *some* locale-related preferences, it is too inconsistent to trust inference. I have two suggestions: (1) Any question including a date should be *explicit* with what the format is, unless it is perfectly unambiguous (as this version of your sample data is ... first version was not). (2) Always change your data to be real `Date`-class from the start. Having dates as strings is infrequently useful.